# Verifying an external signature of a very large file in c#

Tags: c#, digital-signature

i have a large file that needs to be signed in order to be archived. It's a CSV file that is generated once in a month and has a size of > 2Gb (don't ask me what this is good for :) ).
Anyway.. The signing of the file is not the problem, there is a lib for that, i generate the hash and i get my signature.
What i want to do now, is to verify the signature.
tutorials want me to do something like this:

```
byte[] sig = ReadFile(signatureFile);
SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(ReadFile(dataFile)), true);
cms.Decode(sig);
cms.CheckSignature(false);
```

this actually works.. but as you can imagine, i don't feel like loading the entire content of a 2 GB file into memory.

the msdn article about the ContentInfo class tells me, that i can choose the oid for the content, i want my contentInfo initialized with. 
the oid for hashed data would be "1.2.840.113549.1.7.5"
so here i am:

```
byte[] sig = ReadFile(signatureFile);
SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(new byte[]{}), true);
cms.Decode(sig);
SignerInfo inf = cms.SignerInfos[0];
string algorithm = inf.DigestAlgorithm.FriendlyName;
cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.5"), GetHash(algorithm, dataFile)), true);
cms.Decode(sig);
cms.CheckSignature(false);
```

now CheckSignature throws me an exception saying that the hash is incorrect.

the following would work:

```
byte[] sig = ReadFile(signatureFile);
SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(new byte[]{}), true);
cms.Decode(sig)
byte[] compareableHash = GetHash(algorithm, dataFile);
foreach (var t in inf.SignedAttributes)
{
    if (t.Oid.Value == "1.2.840.113549.1.9.4")
    {         
        Pkcs9MessageDigest digest = (Pkcs9MessageDigest)t.Values[0];
        if (CompareableHash(compareableHash, digest.MessageDigest)) // this compares the hashes bytewise
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hash is correct!");
        }
    }
}
```

can i trust this method to be 100% reliable or is there a better way?

Comment: I saw `ContentInfo(new byte[]{})` and made bad assumptions. I've deleted my stupid answer.